# Let's lay out our options and design a better future for [layout-designer]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[layout-designer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout-designer) seems to be used by askers to refer to very different things:

- Software to help a restaurant/apartment/etc manager decide how to place tables/chairs/etc
- Any kind of GUI design tool
- Maybe other things too

Could someone please read the 28 questions and come up with more specific tags? Please post your ideas as answers, thanks!

Comment: Now all retagged - except for two closed questions.  Editing these would place them in the reopen queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start the ball rolling, some suggestions, trying to use existing tags where possible:

[floor-plan](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floor-plan) already exists on 5 questions and can be used for the distribution of chairs & tables.
[data-visualization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) already exists on 228 questions and can be used for the layout of data on a screen.
[user-interface](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) already exists on 80 questions and can be used for the layout of web forms etc on screen.
[desktop-publishing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-publishing) already exists on 11 questions and can be used for the layout of information on a printed page.
[gardening](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) and [landscape](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscape) already exist on 3 and 4 questions respectively (some questions have both tags) and can be used for the layout of gardens of all sizes.

For questions about layout of components on PCBs, I don't believe the existing [electronics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) tag is specific enough.  So, I would suggest creating [pcb-design](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pcb-design).

Many of the, now 30, questions with [layout-designer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout-designer) also have the above suggestions as tags.  So, retagging would be quite a painless process.

Comment: Sounds good! Anyone feel free to retag according to this :-)